# WooCommerce buy page has no navigation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I go to the Buy page on my site where I installed WooCommerce I have no navigation menu. Please take a look at this page: http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/buy-2/

Instead, I navigate to an individual product page there is a navigation menu: http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/product/unbreakable-the-western-states-100/

The menu seems to be working on all the other pages that are related with WooCommerce.

What do I need to do to get the navigation menu back on the main product listing page?

Comment: Probably a theme issue. Hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Adding onto @Aibrean's comment: The template used for the `/jf/buy-2/` page like either has the nav menu commented out, doesn't contain the nav menu, or is using a different nav-menu by default for display.